# Is it okay to use capital img file in html?

Tags: html, image, url

Is it okay to use image file name with capital letter (France.png) in html?
Will it cost a problem when upload to server?

Comment: If you are using "france.png" or "France.png" in localhost. It will works. But It wont work  "france.png" in server

Answer (score 1):

Paths in URLs are case-sensitive according to the standard. That means it does matter how you construct the URL: uppercase, lowercase or a combination of it.

That isn't the full answer though. The server side technology may determine that the case doesn't matter. So if the server doesn't care about it, in the end it doesn't matter.

From my point of view you should always keep in mind that one server might care and another not so always use proper casing of your URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Paths (the bit after the host name) in URLs are case-sensitive. You can use a URL with `France.png` if you want, as long as you name the file `France.png` when you upload it to the server.